# Rust Module Visibility Issue: Cannot Access mod from root

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm working on a Rust project where I'm encountering a compile-time error related to the Queryable derive macro. I have a struct defined in a module named test.rs, and I'm trying to use this struct in main.rs. Here's the relevant code:

in test.rs

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub publickey: String,
    pub createdat: NaiveDateTime,
}
```

And in main.rs, I'm including the module like this:

```
pub mod test
```

if I use `pub mod test` in main.rs, it will show

```
error: cannot find derive macro `Queryable` in this scope
  --> src/test.rs
   |
   | #[derive(Queryable)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider importing this derive macro
   |
   + use diesel::Queryable;
   |
```

but if i remove `pub mod test` use it directly like use `crate::test`, it works well, but i want to use it in other mod, so

just like this in schema.rs

```
diesel::table! {
    login_action (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        publickey -> Varchar,
        actiondata -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

if i use  `pub mod schema` it will show same err

Comment: Images of text violate Stack Overflow guidelines. Please edit your question to include any code or error messages directly as text.

Comment: There is no derive macro `Queryable` in the [`prelude`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) so you'll have to add a `use` statement where you want to use it without it's full path. The full error message, which you have truncated, will also tell you this.

Comment: Please add a proper [mre] with the snippets you posted (without a `use diesel::Queryable` anywhere) I can't recreate it working .